# Error Processing Request: Front controller reached 100 router match iterations

Tags: database

What is up?  Everything was up and now when we try to access the website using any point of entry. Front page, product page etc. I get this error?

```
a:5:{i:0;s:52:"
Front controller reached 100 router match iterations
";i:1;s:401:"
#0 /home/issusa/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(183): Mage::throwException('Front controlle...')
#1 /home/issusa/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#2 /home/issusa/public_html/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#3 /home/issusa/public_html/index.php(80): Mage::run('', 'store')
#4 {main}
";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

I am a newbie, so could anyone help?  I read that we should just reinstall a backup file, which I have.  But how do i do this?

Answer (score 1):

here are some solution for this problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262129/magento-front-controller-reached-100-router-match-iterations-error

https://merchantprotocol.com/knowledgebase/solved-front-controller-reached-100-router-match-iterations/

http://tutorialmagento.com/fixing-front-controller-reached-100-router-match-iterations